# Polymer paper-radio-group allows multiple radio buttons to be select

Tags: polymer-2.0

I'm trying to add a radio group but the radio buttons are allowing multiple selection. I imported only the paper-radio-group. How to make it select only one radio button at a time.

```
<paper-radio-group>
      <p>1) <paper-radio-button name="one">Collect is an aggregation and reduce is a fold operation</paper-radio-button></p>
      <p>2) <paper-radio-button name="two">Collect is an fold and reduce is a aggregation operation</paper-radio-button></p>
      <p>3) <paper-radio-button name="three">Both are the same</paper-radio-button></p>
      <p>4) <paper-radio-button name="four">None of the above</paper-radio-button></p>
      </paper-radio-group>
```

Comment: I am not sure but try to remove <p> tag. and 1)...And be sure to import both paper-radio-group.html and paper-radio-button.html at top of page. Beside it's look correct.

Comment: possible error as https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements/issues/29

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never :)
Add whatever tags you want to add but inside paper radio button tag, it should be fine.

```
<paper-radio-group  >
      <paper-radio-button name="one"> <p>1)Collect is an aggregation and reduce is a fold operation</p></paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="two"><p>2)Collect is an fold and reduce is a aggregation operation</p></paper-radio-button>
     <paper-radio-button name="three">  <p>3)Both are the same</p></paper-radio-button>
       <paper-radio-button name="four"><p>4)None of the above</p></paper-radio-button>
      </paper-radio-group>
```